# How can I define a variable in javascript before using it?

Tags: jquery

I want to do the following:

```
if (htmlEdit) {
    var dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog');
} else {
    var dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog2');
}
```

But if I do that I think dialogDiv will not be available outside of the if-else. How can I declare it so I will be able to use it in another place after the if-else?

Comment: "if" will not create a closure

Comment: your variable scope is inside this JS alone make it as globa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this,

```
 var dialogDiv;
if (htmlEdit) {
    dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog');
} else {
    dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog2');
}
```

Here is a good tutorial,
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

Comment: your variable scope is inside this JS alone make it as global

Comment: This gets my vote because it's the correct basic way of doing it. But it's worth mentioning that once you're out of the beginning stages of learning JS, you should avoid "global namespace pollution". There are many articles out there on how to "namespace" your JS.

Comment: Nothing about his answer suggests that this is a global variable, we could be nested inside a dozen functions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
function test()
{
   var dialogDiv; // its use in only test function
}

If you want to declare globally than declare in script tag like this.

<script language="javascript">

  var dialogDiv;

 // Do your stuff below

  function test()
{
          if (htmlEdit) {
              dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog');
       } else {
           dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog2');
       } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will certainly be able to access it outside of the if statement. Javascript has function scope, which means that you just follow up to the nearest funciton(){} and all variable inside are accessible. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r3WG/1/)

```
if (true) {
    var dialogDiv = 'hi';
} else {
    var dialogDiv = 'bye';
}
alert(dialogDiv)​; //alerts "hi"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

In actuality, when you declare a variable somewhere in the middle of the function like this, it is "declared" at the very top of your scope, and the value is set where ever you think you "declared" it. This is called hoisting, it's done without your consent or control and why it is a good idea to declare all variables at the top of functions so that you don't forget what you are scoping to that level.

```
alert(dialogDiv); //Error because dialogDiv is not defined
(function(){
    alert(dialogDiv); //alerts "undefined" because dialogDiv exists here but has no value yet
    if (true) {
        var dialogDiv = 'hi';
    } else {
        var dialogDiv = 'bye';
    }
    alert(dialogDiv); //alerts "hi"
})()
```

Comment: I would still personally declare it outside the if..else, even if just declaring it null or empty string.

Comment: @GregPettit yes, that would be why I said "it is a good idea to declare all variables at the top of functions"

Comment: D'oh, sorry, I missed that phrase!

Answer (score 0):

Make the dialogDiv global variable so you can access any where in your project. Even Out side and inside your functions too.